# Run gcc command from Qt Creator 5.4.0

Tags: qt, gcc, ide

I am trying to make a little IDE to compile c files. I am running under Ubuntu 14.04 and QtCreator 5.4.0. I wrote this code.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QFile file("hello.c");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
    QProcess::execute("gcc hello.c -o hello");
}
```

Everything is OK until run the gcc command. When I click on the button I get this error:

```
In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and my C code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  printf("Hello World..");

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does it compile when you call the command line directly?  Also, is there a reason you have pasted your example code commented out?

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the code?

Comment: No there is no reason about example code. When I run same gcc command on terminal, it compiles. However, when I run gcc command from Qt Program, it gives that error. Also, when i call the command line directly, it gives same error again.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I commented example code to look better at this site. There is no comment in the original file.

Comment: Can you post the exact output of `ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText()`?

Comment: who dinged this guy?  seems like a perfectly good question to me...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't flushed the QTextStream buffer, so hello.c is empty when you call gcc on it. Use QTextStream 's [`flush()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#flush) to flush the buffer, it also calls flush on the underlying device (the QFile here).